# Different result running pytest coverage in local and github action

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions, code-coverage

Why do I get different coverage results when I do it locally and in the GitHub Actions CI?

Here are the results:

- Locally:

```
pytest tests/test.py --cov=./snmp_collector --cov-report=xml --cov-report=term-missing
================================== test session starts ===================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/benyamin/PycharmProjects/snmp-manager
plugins: timeout-2.1.0, celery-4.4.7, cov-3.0.0
collected 2 items                                                                        

tests/test.py ..                                                                   [100%]


---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.9.10-final-0 -----------
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
snmp_collector/__init__.py                           4      0   100%
snmp_collector/__main__.py                           8      8     0%   3-13
snmp_collector/collect/__init__.py                   0      0   100%
snmp_collector/collect/collector.py                 89     25    72%   12-13, 37-39, 81-84, 87-92, 100-105, 121-133, 140, 153
snmp_collector/event_loop.py                       135     55    59%   18-21, 44-50, 84-85, 116, 127-129, 136-139, 148-156, 166-178, 196-197, 204, 207-209, 215-220, 224-236, 240
snmp_collector/read_conf/__init__.py                 0      0   100%
snmp_collector/read_conf/read_configuration.py      69     17    75%   10-11, 56-57, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 95-98, 107-108, 115-118
snmp_collector/response/__init__.py                  0      0   100%
snmp_collector/response/response.py                 18      1    94%   31
snmp_collector/utility/__init__.py                   0      0   100%
snmp_collector/utility/utility.py                   58     31    47%   24, 26, 29-36, 50, 54-61, 64-85
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                              381    137    64%
```

- In the GitHub Action:

```
Run pytest tests/test.py --cov=./snmp_collector --cov-report=xml --cov-report=term-missing 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.10, pytest-6.2.0, py-1.11.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/runner/work/snmp-manager/snmp-manager
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 2 items

tests/test.py ..     

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.9.10-final-0 -----------
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
snmp_collector/__init__.py                           4      0   100%
snmp_collector/__main__.py                           8      8     0%   3-13
snmp_collector/collect/__init__.py                   0      0   100%
snmp_collector/collect/collector.py                 89     44    51%   12-13, 29-39, 86-133, 140, 153
snmp_collector/event_loop.py                       135     55    59%   18-21, 44-50, 84-85, 116, 127-129, 136-139, 148-156, 166-178, 196-197, 204, 207-209, 215-220, 224-236, 240
snmp_collector/read_conf/__init__.py                 0      0   100%
snmp_collector/read_conf/read_configuration.py      69     17    75%   10-11, 56-57, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 95-98, 107-108, 115-118
snmp_collector/response/__init__.py                  0      0   100%
snmp_collector/response/response.py                 18      1    94%   29
snmp_collector/utility/__init__.py                   0      0   100%
snmp_collector/utility/utility.py                   58     31    47%   24, 26, 29-36, 50, 54-61, 64-85
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                              381    156    59%
```

Apparently, the major difference is related to the `snmp_collector/collect/collector.py` file.

---

Also here's the [repo](https://github.com/agn-7/snmp-manager).

Comment: From the coverage I can see that [these lines](https://github.com/agn-7/snmp-manager/blob/master/snmp_collector/collect/collector.py#L81-L84) don't get run on your local machine, but they do get run on Github Actions. That means it must rely on something outside of the tests, e.g. some configuration that you've done on your local machine, but not in Github CI. Usually you should mock out code that needs external dependencies. In this case, I would mock out `getCmd`.

Comment: @DMalan oh I see. thanks for your response. it is most likely related to the OS and network because in my local PC there is a network while in the GitHub actions there's not.

Comment: @DMalan Even though it might be a stupid question, how did you realize the difference between local coverage and GitHub actions coverage you mentioned ([these lines](https://github.com/agn-7/snmp-manager/blob/master/snmp_collector/collect/collector.py#L81-L84))?

Comment: I looked at the report you put in your question and looked at which lines weren't run in each environment (i.e. the line numbers listed under "missing") :)